# I am trying to integrate Agora Voice Calling in my app, but getting java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: android, java-native-interface, agora.io

**I am getting the error on the following line:**

```
AgoraAPIOnlySignal m_agoraAPI = AgoraAPIOnlySignal.getInstance(this, appID);
```

in AGApplication. Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

In case you need the stack trace

```
 java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void io.agora.NativeAgoraAPI.jniInitGet() (tried Java_io_agora_NativeAgoraAPI_jniInitGet and Java_io_agora_NativeAgoraAPI_jniInitGet__)
    at io.agora.NativeAgoraAPI.jniInitGet(Native Method)
    at io.agora.AgoraAPIOnlySignal.getInstance(AgoraAPIOnlySignal.java:60)
    at live.smartify.community.smartliving.security.application.AGApplication.setupAgoraEngine(AGApplication.java:82)
    at live.smartify.community.smartliving.security.application.AGApplication.onCreate(AGApplication.java:67)
```

Comment: Did you load a native library (using `System.loadLibrary`) that contains this symbol?

Comment: I Suppose, it must be loaded by Agora library itself. They haven't mentioned it to do by application developer in their documentation.

Comment: Step 4 of the [quick start](https://docs.agora.io/en/Voice/start_call_android?platform=Android) mentions creating an RtcEngine first. That seems like code that would load the corresponding library.

Answer (score 0):

The Agora Signaling SDK is a separate SDK that is not bundled with Agora's native SDKS, so you do have to download and link/add to your project separately from the Native SDK.

The Agora Signaling SDK has been deprecated, you should use [Agora.io's RTM SDK](https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/product_rtm?platform=All%20Platforms), it has all the features of the Signaling SDK along with some new ones.

Make sure to download the SDK and link it within your project. Once you have the SDK installed in your project you can init using:

```
public void init() {
    try {
        mRtmClient = RtmClient.createInstance(mContext, APPID, new RtmClientListener() {
            @Override
            public void onConnectionStateChanged(int state, int reason) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Connection state changes to " + state + " reason: " + reason);
            }

            @Override
            public void onMessageReceived(RtmMessage rtmMessage, String peerId) {
                String msg = rtmMessage.getText();
                Log.d(TAG, "Message received " + " from " + peerId + msg);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "RTM SDK initialization fatal error!");
        throw new RuntimeException("You need to check the RTM initialization process.");
    }
}
```

See Full Android RTM SDK QuickStart Guide: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/messaging_android?platform=Android